# kivy find all TextInputs

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I was trying to register all TextInputs and Spinner in my GUI.
Each of these does have a variable `gid`.

The problem with the `root_widget.walk()` method is that I have different tabs and it does not load the widgets that have not been displayed yet.

However this is not my biggest problem.

The thing is that the `walk()`method does only show Widgets and not TextInputs nor Spinner.

> My question now is: How do you traverse EVERY object (TextInputs/Spinner etc.) including those that have not been displayed yet (in a different tab)

I am very happy for any kind of help or advice.

Greetings, Finn

Answer (score 0):

The `walk()` widget method does visit all child widgets (including `TextInput` and `Spinner`. If you are using `TabbedPanel` as your root widget, then the following will register all your widgets (if it is called by a binding to `on_draw`):

```
registered = False
def on_draw(*args):
    global registered
    if registered:
        return  # just to avoid running this many times
    registered = True
    app = App.get_running_app()
    for tab in root_widget.tab_list: # assumes root_widget is a TabbedPanel
        if tab.content is not None:
            for widget in tab.content.walk():
                app.register_widget(widget)
```

A similar construct could be done if you are using a `ScreenManager` as your root widget.